# Error when trying to fit an exponential distribution to data using Python

Tags: python, scipy, distribution, curve-fitting, exponential

I am struggling to fit an exponential distribution like:

p(x) = lambda * exp (-lambda * x)

to the following dataset:

```
y = [1.0 0.6477204485713643 0.5740407723417333 0.5615636591299797
 0.4387673913917531 0.40091370516517705 0.3557117110132781
 0.3511355853065214 0.340307340921202 0.30971826267036 0.292891403862456
 0.2467743233580864 0.2266046083821163 0.21720917030949116
 0.20043871451165768 0.1973221582209641 0.15362640051482043
 0.15354057195269372 0.14662893640148297 0.14317539711005514
 0.11807717376369412 0.10370859482950556 0.10093677560919409
 0.09749966756865966 0.08933073156729388 0.0804544088313465
 0.0761310467698398 0.0761310467698398 0.0560272314739388
 0.054424966400080085 0.04830594736471987 0.04614770045710077
 0.04596980503252967 0.03156586444228013 0.031247687808906088
 0.02034784444410579 0.01648966866320673 0.016039148970427325
 0.014211493240353406 0.011831876417890502 0.010697649767138983
 0.008203782016905766 0.00668207490883694 0.006385472749205766
 0.004654267333597479 0.003107036846521259 0.0022789222224917083
 0.0018466098136964094 0.0012186574760257173 0.0009770057014847977
 0.0007631859286121455 0.0006151192857729099 0.0006139225669891776
 0.0005757713710793208 0.00037491693850308307 0.00037491693850308307
 0.00020552292850767692 9.51226931808377e-05]
```

I have tried the following:

```
from scipy.stats import expon

loc, scale = expon.fit(y, floc=0)
```

This should be super easy but for some reason I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question so that `y` is valid syntax? Currently, it's not a valid list that would allow us to look at this locally without going through and replacing all the commas.

Comment: if you use correct list syntax, it seems to work as expected, i.e., `y = [1, 0.64, ...]`

Comment: Sure, so do I have to manually insert the commas or is there a smarter way to print it with python?

Comment: `y` is a `ndarray` of shape `(58,)`. Actually the `min` and `max` attributes of the object are `{str} 'not a numeric object'`, which is also weird...

Comment: `print y.tolist()` and then copy/paste that. I'm not sure of a simple way for us to do the reverse on our end from what you posted. It would probably have been quicker for me to do it manually but then it makes it easier for others to look into too :)

Comment: I can't believe it... It works with the `tolist()`... Shall I close the post or leave it?

Comment: I'm looking for other examples. I guess `stats` still iterates through the array and then fails when trying to use `isinfinite`. I don't suppose it's obvious that it would fail for an array, I'd keep the question open for an answer (or answer it yourself). Then again, why _would_ `scipy` fail for an array but not a list?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser My dataset is empirical values observed in the nature, which I have ordered. At the end of the day, since it is ordered, the two methods would yield to the same outcome. I am gonna try it as soon as I have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, thanks to rojanjosh comments, the input is an `object`-type.

The latter does not work with the fit function. Therefore, this has to be converted:

**Solution #1:**

`loc, scale = expon.fit(y.astype(np.float64), floc=0)`

**Solution #2:**

`loc, scale = expon.fit(y.tolist(), floc=0)`

Make sure to check the input type of `y` using `y.dtype` before passing it to the `fit` function.

Comment: What happens if you try `loc, scale = expon.fit(y[:-1], floc=0)`?

Comment: Ok, and what do you get from `print(y.dtype)`?

Comment: @roganjosh I get `object` as a type... maybe that's the issue

Comment: Bingo. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808327/unexpected-exception-in-numpy-isfinite) gives a broader explanation. Also, `loc, scale = expon.fit(y.astype(np.float64), floc=0)` should hopefully fix it. This is much better than the solution being to convert it to a list.

Comment: @roganjosh It does! Even `loc, scale = expon.fit(y.astype(float), floc=0)` works. I will update the answer. Thanks a lot for your help!