# TypeError using statsmodels.tsa.seasonal

Tags: time-series, statsmodels

I'm trying to decompose a time series. my date doesn't contain Nan and inf and its index is 'datetime64[ns]. yet for some reasons I can't understand, running the following :

```
statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose(data, model='additive',filt=None, freq=None, two_sided=True)
```

gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

My data looks like this:

```
ds
2005-01-01    1.56832e+06
2005-02-01    1.77795e+06
2005-03-01    1.89924e+06
2005-04-01    2.19562e+06
2005-05-01    2.25281e+06
2005-06-01    2.20942e+06
2005-07-01    2.13806e+06
2005-08-01    2.15816e+06
```

I'm getting this series from a data frame:

```
    y   ds
ds      
2005-01-01  1.56832e+06 2005-01-01 00:00:00
2005-02-01  1.77795e+06 2005-02-01 00:00:00
2005-03-01  1.89924e+06 2005-03-01 00:00:00
2005-04-01  2.19562e+06 2005-04-01 00:00:00
2005-05-01  2.25281e+06 2005-05-01 00:00:00
```

using the following code:

```
df.columns = ['y','ds']
df[~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any(1)]
df.index= df.ds
data = df.y      #data is the time series I want to decompose
```

System Info: Python 3.5.1 | Pandas 0.20.3 | Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808327/unexpected-exception-in-numpy-isfinite, possible the same cause

Comment: Thanks, I've already seen that answer but it doesn't apply to my case

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.

Check if the type is an integer. If it is not, convert it.

```
data.dtypes
dtype('int32')
```