# Can I detrend and de-seasonalize an entire pandas dataframe using seasonal_decompose?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, statsmodels

I am working on a timeseries dataset of a retailers transactions the previous 3 years. I want to get rid of any trend lines and seasonality before I use machine learning.

These are the columns and the DType of the datafreame (ds1):

```
Int64Index: 538435 entries, 0 to 538642
Data columns (total 20 columns):

   Column                   Non-Null Count   Dtype         
---  ------                   --------------   -----         
 0   WEEK_END_DATE            538435 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 1   UNITS                    538435 non-null  int64         
 2   PRICE                    538435 non-null  float64       
 3   FEATURE                  538435 non-null  int64         
 4   DISPLAY                  538435 non-null  int64         
 5   TPR_ONLY                 538435 non-null  int64         
 6   DESCRIPTION              538435 non-null  object        
 7   MANUFACTURER             538435 non-null  object        
 8   CATEGORY                 538435 non-null  object        
 9   SUB_CATEGORY             538435 non-null  object        
 10  PRODUCT_SIZE             538435 non-null  object        
 11  ADDRESS_STATE_PROV_CODE  538435 non-null  object        
 12  MSA_CODE                 538435 non-null  int64         
 13  SEG_VALUE_NAME           538435 non-null  object        
 14  PARKING_SPACE_QTY        538435 non-null  float64       
 15  SALES_AREA_SIZE_NUM      538435 non-null  int64         
 16  AVG_WEEKLY_BASKETS       538435 non-null  float64       
 17  Units_a_visit            538435 non-null  float64       
 18  Visits_per_hhs           538435 non-null  float64       
 19  DISCOUNT                 538435 non-null  float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(6), int64(6), object(7)
memory usage: 86.3+ MB
```

I have tried the following:

```
from pandas import Series
from matplotlib import pyplot
import statsmodels.api as sm 
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
ds1.index = ds1.WEEK_END_DATE
result = seasonal_decompose(ds1, model='additive')
result.plot()
pyplot.show()
```

as well as

```
res = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(ds1.interpolate())
res.plot()
```

For both I get the following error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-322daa0c1fd6> in <module>()
      6 ds1.index = ds1.WEEK_END_DATE
      7 
----> 8 result = seasonal_decompose(ds1)
      9 result.plot()
     10 pyplot.show()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/statsmodels/tsa/seasonal.py in seasonal_decompose(x, model, filt, freq, two_sided, extrapolate_trend)
    113     nobs = len(x)
    114 
--> 115     if not np.all(np.isfinite(x)):
    116         raise ValueError("This function does not handle missing values")
    117     if model.startswith('m'):

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I have also tried to only analyse the int and floats:

```
numeric = ['UNITS','PRICE','FEATURE','DISPLAY','TPR_ONLY','PARKING_SPACE_QTY','SALES_AREA_SIZE_NUM','AVG_WEEKLY_BASKETS','Units_a_visit','Visits_per_hhs','DISCOUNT']
from pandas import Series
from matplotlib import pyplot
import statsmodels.api as sm 
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
result = seasonal_decompose(ds1[numeric], model='additive')
result.plot()
pyplot.show()
```

As well as change all the object's into dummy variables before using the code.

None works. Anyone any suggestions?

Comment: `WEEK_END_DATE` probably needs to be the index.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decomposing trend, seasonal and residual time series elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457281/decomposing-trend-seasonal-and-residual-time-series-elements)

Comment: Thank you! I have now set WEEK_END_DATE as index but get the following error message: ```TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''````

Comment: The following stackoverflow post says it only works for numeric columns, but I have tried that and it doesnt resolve the error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432096/typeerror-using-statsmodels-tsa-seasonal

Comment: I would try with 1 column to see if it works. Or test each column in succession to see if there is an issue with one.